# Keras model.predict, InvalidArgumentError, ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

I am using the unit standard network and I can easily train it with keras. But when I want to use model.predict I get the following error massage, InvalidArgument. I have no idea why this is happening.
I have my input shape when training network as [H,W,3],and the same shape when doing the model.predict

Can anyone help?

I also put my unit network and the way I train.

```
def UNet(n_input_channels, n_output_channels):
from keras.layers import Input, Dropout, UpSampling2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, Conv2D, Concatenate
from keras.models import Model

inputs = Input((None, None, n_input_channels))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
conv5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)
conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
conv5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)
drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
merge6 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv4,up6])
conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
conv6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)
conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)
conv6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)

up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
merge7 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv3,up7])
conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
conv7 = BatchNormalization()(conv7)
conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)
conv7 = BatchNormalization()(conv7)

up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
merge8 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv2,up8])
conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
conv8 = BatchNormalization()(conv8)
conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)
conv8 = BatchNormalization()(conv8)

up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
merge9 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv1,up9])
conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
conv10 = Conv2D(n_output_channels, 1, activation = 'softmax')(conv9)

return Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv10)
```

and do the training as:

```
model_unet = UNet(n_input_channels=3, n_output_channels=3)
model_unet.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])
history_unet = model_unet.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batchsize, epochs=epochs, 
                    verbose=1, shuffle=True, 
                    validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))
```

and the model.predict

```
predictions = model.predict(sample_images, batch_size=4)

InvalidArgumentError

/work/banafsheh.beheshtipour/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2115             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2116             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2117                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2118             return result
   2119 

<decorator-gen-60> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/work/banafsheh.beheshtipour/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

/work/banafsheh.beheshtipour/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.pyc in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1191         else:
   1192             st = clock2()
-> 1193             exec(code, glob, local_ns)
   1194             end = clock2()
   1195             out = None

<timed exec> in <module>()

<ipython-input-39-6b97b7df800f> in predict(model, num_samples, indices)
     10     sample_masks = masks[samples_ind, :142, :92]
     11     print samplep_images.shape
---> 12     predictions = model.predict(sample_images, batch_size=4)
     13     toc = time.time()
     14     print('Time per image = {:.4f} sec'.format((toc-tic) / num_samples))

/work/banafsheh.beheshtipour/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps)
   1167                                             batch_size=batch_size,
   1168                                             verbose=verbose,
-> 1169                                             steps=steps)
   1170 
   1171     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

/work/banafsheh.beheshtipour/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.pyc in predict_loop(model, f, ins, batch_size, verbose, steps)
    292                 ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    293 
--> 294             batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    295             batch_outs = to_list(batch_outs)
    296             if batch_index == 0:

/work/banafsheh.beheshtipour/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in __call__(self, inputs)
   2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)
   2716         else:
   2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

/work/banafsheh.beheshtipour/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in _call(self, inputs)
   2673             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2674         else:
-> 2675             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2676         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2677 

/work/banafsheh.beheshtipour/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1380           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1381               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1382               run_metadata_ptr)
   1383         if run_metadata:
   1384           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/work/banafsheh.beheshtipour/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.pyc in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    517             None, None,
    518             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 519             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    520     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    521     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,512,17,11] vs. shape[1] = [1,512,16,10]
     [[Node: concatenate_1/concat = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](batch_normalization_8/cond/Merge, conv2d_11/Relu, concatenate_1/concat-2-LayoutOptimizer)]]
```

Comment: using of different kernel size of 2 and 3 is willful? Because padding can cause some phenomenon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Saugat Bhattarai to help me about finding the answer. I found that to do the prediction, your image size needs to be any power of 2. So the H and W can be 8,32,64,128,.... There is no need to have the exact same image size for the training and prediction as long as the size is a power of two. So I tried my case with training data images with size (32,32,3) and prediction with (128,128,3) and it perfectly worked. 
Hope this helps other people.

Comment: I guess they need not strictly be powers of two. Any multiples of 2 raised to the number of downsampling/upsampling stages should work. I mean, if you have 5 downsampling stages, then any multiple of 32 like `(160,96,3)` should also work.

Answer (score 3):

Double check your input shape you want to give to your model.

> inputs = Input((None, None, n_input_channels))

Input shape while training model and prediction should be same.(H, W , channel)

> InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match:
>   shape[0] = [1,512,17,11] vs. shape[1] = [1,512,16,10]

**Updated:**
Resize Input size to (32,32,3)

```
img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32))
```

**Note:** Change variable according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I checked the inputs, they are the same, but the H and W in them are different, does that matter?
When train it is (32,32,3) and when predict (142,92,3)

Comment: I tried adding one dimension with the way you said, but it gives me this error:  
Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 142, 92, 3)

Comment: OMG! I changed the prediction size to (32,32,3) and it doesn't show any error!!! Why? I have done this prediction with other models (like MSD) and it never had any issue with having different H,W for the input train and predict images

Comment: In that case you don't have to add dimension. Your issue is you didn't size your image for prediction. First resize your image to (32,32,3). Code below
    img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32)) 
    print ("Image After Resize",img.shape)

Comment: The logic is the feature used for training should be same for prediciton 32 * 32 + 3 channel. i.e input size should be same for both. What MSD did please do research? Might be MSD is flexible about input size?

Comment: I found it, the image size only needs to be a power of two, no matter if it is the same as the training size or not. Thank you so much for helping me to find the write answer.